# RelativeLayout fill parent not available

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3, the default layout is ContraintLayout. I was able to find the way how to change to RelativeLayout changing it in the XML code.

My problem is that the fill parent is not available then for each item, there is "none" instead. However match_wrap & fill_parent are available.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the screen with the relative layout you can use

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

`fill_parent` is now Deprecated you can refer this here [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) Use `match_parent` instead. To change ConstraintLayout to RelativeLayout you can change the Root layout while creating the file or Directly replace the ConstraintLayout to RelativeLayout in XML also(Studio Handles it well).